# Power Bi how can I merge my data to create a new value

Tags: powerbi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCgfr.jpg)I need to merge some of my data to create one common value. It is easier to explain as an example. My data consists of customer queries and of which some can be complaints. Therefore my issue description can either be issue 1 or issue 1 complaint. I want to merge these two together to create just issue 1

Hoping to just have this on one tab and not across the whole power bi database. Also there are around 30 different issues so need to do this for all so the simpler, the better!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add some sample data and an expected output?

Comment: Hi i could not work out how to add the sample data, so i have included a screenshot of some mock data. I need a bar chart with the short descriptions along the X axis and the bars will be a count of the incidents. The short descriptions should not be separate if one is a complaint. E.g. Login + Complaint Login = Login and so on. @Jonee